# Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message '1048

Tags: php, mysqli

So I want to insert a new user in my db, but when I want to post my registration, this error pops up:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message '1048' in 
C:\xampp\htdocs\Zephryte\app\classes\users.class.php:110 Stack trace: #0 
C:\xampp\htdocs\Zephryte\index.php(5): users->register() #1 {main} thrown in 
C:\xampp\htdocs\Zephryte\app\classes\users.class.php on line 110
```

I do know that this comes from my MySQLi connection, but I don't know what it means or what to do with it...

This is the code that produces the error:

```
$query->bind_param('ssssssssssssssssssssss', $data, $_POST['username'], $_POST['password'], $een, $_POST['email'], $code, $ipAddress, $ipAddress, $data, $data, $een, $null, $null, $nul, $nul, $een, $een, $nul, $_POST['skype'], $nul, $nul, $null); //106

$query->execute(); //107

if (!$query->execute()) //108

{ //109

    throw new Exception($this->db->conn->errno, 1); //110

} //111

$query->close(); //112
```

Does anyone of you guys know what the error is, and how to solve it?

Thanks.

Comment: What are `$nul`, `$null`, `$een`, and the rest of the variables you got in there?  Are those *all* set correctly?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22444873/php-mysql-execute-failed-1048-column-title-cannot-be-null-error http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25154105/error-1048-23000-column-cannot-be-null-however-i-am-inserting-valid-data

Comment: Per the docs: [`1048: Column cannot be null...`](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?98,576167,576167). One of your columns appears to be `NULL`.

Comment: Replace `throw new Exception($this->db->conn->errno, 1);` with `die($query->error);`.  That should give you something more useful.

Answer (score 0):

Your query is failing because you missed one of the columns off.

I couldn't say which was missing but

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php

Will give more info

Answer (score 0):

The mysql docs reveal that the error is probably a null column.
http://www.mysqlfaqs.net/mysql-faqs/Errors/1048-Column-cannot-be-null

The number that was in the exception is the mysql errno and that is he key. all that you have to do is google `mysql 1048` to find the mysql error documentation.